# reset the timer while user is typing or clicking the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, timeout, reset

I want to reset the timer while user is typing in input or clicking the screen.
Here's my code, but it doesn't reset the timer.
Can you tell me where is the problem and how should I solve it ?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".data-lock").click(function() {
        $(this).animate({
            bottom: '100%'
        }, function() {
            $(".back-img").addClass("lock-up");
            $(".logbox").addClass("logboxinfead");
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(".data-lock").animate({
                    bottom: '0'
                }, function() {
                    $(".back-img").removeClass("lock-up");
                    $(".logbox").removeClass("logboxinfead");
                });
            }, 30000);
        });
    });
    var idleInterval = setInterval(timerIncrement(), 60000); // 1 minute

    //Zero the idle timer on mouse movement.
    $(this).mousemove(function(e) {
        idleTime = 0;
    });
    $(this).keypress(function(e) {
        idleTime = 0;
    });
});

function timerIncrement() {
    idleTime = idleTime + 1;
    if (idleTime > 19) { // 20 minutes
        window.location.reload();
    }
});
```

Comment: can you put the related html code in order to easy "copy and paste" reproduction and try to help you?

Comment: $(this).click(function (e) {
        idleTime = 0;
        if(idleInterval) {
           clearInterval(idleInterval);
           idleInterval = null;
        }
    });
    $(this).keypress(function (e) {
        idleTime = 0;
        if(idleInterval) {
           clearInterval(idleInterval);
           idleInterval = null;
        }
    });

Answer (score 0):

You have to call 'clearInterval' to stop the timer as below. Also I changed the 'mousemove' to 'click' below.

```
$(this).click(function (e) {
        idleTime = 0;
        if(idleInterval) {
           clearInterval(idleInterval);
           idleInterval = null;
        }
    });
    $(this).keypress(function (e) {
        idleTime = 0;
        if(idleInterval) {
           clearInterval(idleInterval);
           idleInterval = null;
        }
    });
```